# MOV into a register specified by macro argument

Tags: assembly, macros, avr, atmelstudio

I'm trying to execute a `mov` operation in a macro in AVR assembly. I want to specify the target by a numeric argument to a macro. I am using the Atmel Studio assembler.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
; accepts 1 argument: target register.
.macro move_r10_into
  mov @0, r10 
.endmacro

; usage example:
move_r10_into 1 ; So this should do mov r1, r10
```

But when doing it like this, I get the error "Invalid register". Using `r@0` instead gives the error "Unexpected (". Trying `(r@0)` results in "unexpected REGISTER".

How do I do this?

Comment: I guess you'd need a `token paste operator` but I can't find that in the manual. As a workaround, consider passing the entire register name (ie. `r1`) as the argument.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like what I'm trying to figure out. I don't want to pass the entire register name since I want to use it in a macro where I loop over the different values.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't notice this had been mentioned as a workaround in a comment by [jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) as I was typing, but passing in the full register name does work. I just added a few lines so it could easily be tested in the simulator:

```
.macro move_r10_into
    mov @0, r10 
.endmacro

inc r10
move_r10_into r1
nop
```

However you've mentioned in a comment wanting to be able to call it from a loop. Check the datasheet for your specific device but typically the registers R0-31 are mapped into data addresses 0x00 - 0x1F. That means you can access them using indirect data access by making use of  the pointer registers as in the following example:

```
.macro move_r10_into
    ldi zl, @0 ; Load data address into Z pointer
    ldi zh, 0  ; This will result in R30/31 being changed
    st z, r10
.endmacro

inc r10
move_r10_into 1 ; So this should do mov r1, r10
nop
```