# How do I do this AVR assembly more elegantly

Tags: assembly, avr, atmelstudio, attiny

I've currently got this code:

```
// takes a table reference as an argument
.macro load_table_into_r0_to_r8
    ldi ZL, low(2*@0)
    ldi ZH, high(2*@0)
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r0, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r1, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r2, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r3, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r4, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r5, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r6, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r7, r25
    lpm r25, Z+
    mov r8, r25
.endm
```

As you can see, a lot of really similar code is repeated.

It would be ridiculous if there isn't a way to write this in a shorter fashion, like with `.irp` or maybe `.if`s. However, I can't get that to work. For `.irp` I tried this:

```
.irp i, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
   lpm r25, Z+
   mov r\i, r25
.endr
```

While Atmel Studio does highlight `.irp` (it doesn't other highlight everything that starts with a `.`) it doesn't work: `Invalid directive: '.irp'`

See also my other, related question: [MOV into a register specified by macro argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275900/mov-into-a-register-specified-by-macro-argument).

Comment: Why not simply `lpm r\i, Z+` ?

Comment: because you can't `lpm` into `r0` to `r16`

Comment: Oh indeed!  Why not copying register pairs (it takes only 1 cycle to copy 2 bytes): "lpm to r24", "lpm to r25", "load r0-r1 with r24-r25" ?

Comment: I don't think I have a `load` instruction...

Comment: Sorry my pseudocode :)  The correct instruction name is `movw`

Comment: Thanks, the correct syntax was `movw r0:r1, r25:r26`.

Comment: And in the end you were right, I could in fact `lpm` into the lower registers as well, just not `ldi`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this doesn't directly answer your question, but are you aware of the fact that AVR registers are memory mapped at address zero? So you could use a runtime memory copy loop instead of this macro construct. Unbeknownst to me, you might of course have some other constraints that rule this option out.

Comment: Jumps cost 2 cycles and I need to use as few cycles as possible.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something like that when I was talking about unknown constraints :)